# Setting a Node.js Object to data read from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, readfile, fs

I want to read data from a file and add it to an Object stored in memory. The data in the file text.txt looks roughly like this:

```
One: {title: 'One' ,
contributor: 'Fred',
summary: 'blah' ,
comments: 'words' },

Two: {title: 'Two' ,
contributor: 'Chris' ,
summary: 'blah blah i'm a blah' ,
comments: '' },
```

I'm trying to set it to an empty Object like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var text = Object.create(null);
fs.readFile("./public/text.txt", "utf-8", function(error, data) {
  text = { data };
});
```

However, when I log `text` to the console, it comes out looking like this:

```
{ data: 'One: {title: \'One\' ,\ncontributor: \'Fred\',\nsummary: \'blah\' ,\ncomments: \'words\' },\n    \nTwo: {title: \'Two\' ,\ncontributor: \'Chris\' ,\nsummary: \'blah blah i\'m a blah\' ,\ncomments: \'\' },\n\n' }
```

Apparently, it's reading `data` as a key. What I really want, though, is something more like so:

```
{
  One: {title: 'One' ,
  contributor: 'Fred',
  summary: 'blah' ,
  comments: 'words' },

  Two: {title: 'Two' ,
  contributor: 'Chris' ,
  summary: 'blah blah i'm a blah' ,
  comments: '' },
}
```

Any advice here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Real simple: just use `JSON.parse(data);`.  See duplicate: [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON object into (server) memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory)

Comment: I tried that solution. When I do that I get `Syntax Error: Unexpected token O`

Comment: It just occured to me that a possible solution to that syntax error is to wrap everything in the text.txt file inside some `{}` curly brackets. That creates some difficulties for me; is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Q: `Syntax Error: Unexpected token O`.  A: Then your Json file is illegal.  SUGGESTION: make sure you've got `{...}` delimiting your outermost "data" node.  The answer to the question you posted is "use JSON.parse()".  The answer to your syntax error is "fix your JSON file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of Node, then you have support for ES6.

```
// So your code 
`text = { data }` 

// is actually a shortcut for 
`text = { data: data }`
```

That's why you end up with an object that has the key data and the value is a string version of what was found in the file. Instead, just use JSON.parse on the data parameter (which is a string) and it'll convert it to an Object, which you can store in text. Like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
var text = Object.create(null);
fs.readFile("./public/text.txt", "utf-8", function(error, data) {
  text = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

You'll also need to make the file valid json. Which means keys need quotes around them as do String values.

```
{
  "One": {
    "title": "One" ,
    "contributor": "Fred",
    "summary": "blah" ,
    "comments": "words"
  },

  "Two": {
    "title": "Two" ,
    "contributor": "Chris" ,
    "summary": "blah blah i'm a blah" ,
    "comments": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Comment: Oops sorry, ya updated my answer with the other issues

Comment: Urgh.... Welp, that's probably the best I'm gonna get. Fair solution. I'm gonna leave this open to see if anybody chimes in with a way to do this without wrapping the whole thing in brackets.

Comment: You could load it as a Javascript file using require() but you'd need to add a line for exporting

Comment: Or use a better extended file system like fs-extra or node-jsonfile, but you'll notice they just do it for you: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile/blob/master/index.js#L14

Comment: Well, wrapping the whole thing in brackets is way easier than I thought -- `fs.writeFile("./public/text.txt", JSON.stringify(text), function(error) {
        if (error) throw error;
        }
      });` That solves my whole problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is use `eval`, which is the only way if you really don't want to edit the file to be valid JSON or to export an object as @Spidy suggested. Just be sure the file is valid JavaScript, because the example you gave had

```
summary: 'blah blah i'm a blah'
```

but you need to escape `i'm` like `i\'m`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var text = {};
fs.readFile('./public/text.txt', 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
  eval(`text = {${data}}`);
//eval('text = {' + data + '}');
});
```

But I wouldn't necessarily recommend that because that allows arbitrary javascript to get executed. Depending on how the data in the file gets there it would be a huge security risk.