# Node - Loading a JSON file into code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node app. In this app, I have a directory structure like this:

```
library/
  ents/
    index.js
index.js
package.json
settings.json
```

My settings.json file looks like this:

**settings.json**

```
{
  "url":"http://www.example.com"
}
```

There's more in the file, but that's not relevant to this question. In the ./library/ents/index.js file I have the following:

```
let settings = require('../../settings');
console.log(settings);
```

This executes. But, I was expecting to see the contents of the settings.json file printed out. Instead, I just see `{}`. I really don't understand why this would happen.

Comment: Have you tried the requiring with the JSON file with the `.json` file ending, like `require('../../settings.json')`?

Comment: I reproduced your folder structure and copy-pasted your json and code, it works fine. Are you sure your json file is not empty? Did you try using an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require is for loading amd modules, not for reading json in this manner, if you wish to keep yout file as true json, you can try something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file', 'utf8'));
```

Taken from [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON object into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory)

Comment: Just a reminder - better wrap it in try/catch, both FS operations and JSON.parse may throw exceptions.

Comment: `require()` is commonly used to load/parse JSON files, you can see an example in [npm's doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Answer (score 0):

You could change settings.json to settings.js which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "url":"http://www.example.com"
}
```

then

```
let settings = require('../../settings');
```