# Node GET request for json file not working

Tags: json, node.js, get, filesystems

I'm using NodeJS to build a sample page just for some learning. 
I'm trying to send a GET request to a file in the project's directory (using request module of node). The callback is just returning me an error and I can't figure out why this is happening.
Here's the code:

```
request.get(__dirname+"/public/app/test.json",function(err,data){
    if(!err)
    {
        res.json(data);
        console.log("Test Data Sent!");
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(err);
        console.log("error occured! "+err);
    }
});
```

The console log says this: "Error: Invalid URI e:/directory/nodejs/node-project/public/app/test.json"

Here's my directory structure: (Bold means folders)

**E:**

----**directory**

--------**nodejs**

------------**node-project**

------------server.js

------------package.json

----------------**public**

--------------------**app**

--------------------test.json

Can someone point out the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON object into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET is a http request made to a web server. You can't GET a local file directly.

A local file can be read with [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

Comment: Right. That makes sense.
Thanks a lot (Y)