# Read and Write file using vs code extension

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i am building an extension to parse json using vs code extension.
so my need is ,it should be able able to load .json file from a particular folder and iterate through content of the file.
Then it should allow user to select few keys from it make a new json file out of this and save it in any folder.

But i am not able to find any way to read and write files in "vs code extension".Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to read the current edit state of a file you can use the following API [workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace) function:

```
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri).then((document) => {
  let text = document.getText();
});
```

This will show you the current state of the file including unpersisted changes. `document` is of type [`TextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextDocument) and has `isDirty` set to `true` if it has pending changes.

Answer (score 7):

Since the extension runs in nodejs, you should be able to use any nodejs module built-in or installed by npm in the usual way.

For your purpose you will be OK with the built-in **fs** module: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html

In your extension you will need to import the required module, so your code file should contain this:

```
let fs = require("fs");
```

and then use the methods in the usual way, eg. `fs.fileReadSync( filename, encoding )` ...

Please not that there is one exception. If you install a nodejs module containing compiled, binary code, it will not run in the extension and instead you will see an error message saying something like **%1 is not a valid Win32 application.**  Pure javascript modules are OK, though.

Answer (score 5):

VSCode extensions are running in node.js.  Therefore you can use any available node.js package/module within your extension.  For instance, check out [this question for reading JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory).

Answer (score 1):

For JSON, you just need to `require` or `import` the JSON file, such as:

```
const jsonObject = require('./myJSONfile.json');
// do something
```

For JSON with comments, you can use [node-jsonc-parser](https://github.com/Microsoft/node-jsonc-parser).

After the manipulation, you could use the `fs` module of nodej.js to write to the disk.