# Reading json files using nodejs and request gives Error: Invalid URI at request.ini

Tags: node.js, request

I want to read a json file from my folder and putting the result into my nodejs controller.

```
var request = require('request');
request('../global/language/gb.json', function (err, res, body) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(importedJSON);
    }
})
```

I keep getting

```
Error: Invalid URI "../global/language/gb.json"
    at Request.init (G:\Dropbox\ThaiHome\Github\server\node_modules\request\request.js
```

Is that because it only likes a real http URL?

Or is there another way to read a json file from the harddisk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON object into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to just require your json file. I think you can't use `request` for your local files directly, you need some URI.

`var result = require('../global/language/gb.json');`

Comment: Waou! I had no idea it was that simple - thanks Alendorff!!