# How to make GET request with express.js to a local json file?

Tags: json, node.js, express

I want to make a GET request to a local JSON file with express.

In my server.js I have this

```
var data = {};
app.get('/src/assets/data.json', (req, res) => {
  console.log(res)
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  });

  res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

data.json looks like this

```
[{
    "param": "one",
    "param": "two",
    "param": "three"
  }]
```

Also I made a function for GET request which is called as soon as the DOM is loaded

```
getData() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/src/assets/data.json', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr)
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
```

I'm getting a response back but it is an empty object. I'm guessing it is because in my server file `var data = {};` is empty but I'm not sure what to do with it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why don't you simply just send the file you requested for

```
var data = {};
app.get('/src/assets/data.json', (req, res) => {
  console.log(res)

  /* Insted of doing all this */
  // res.writeHead(200, {
  //    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  // });
  // res.end(JSON.stringify(data));

  /* Just send the file */
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/src/assets', 'data.json'));
});
```

---

But if you want to just do as your code, what you need to include in your code is

1. Read the `data.json` file.
2. Put all data from the file into object i.e. `data` variable.

To read the file, you need to include [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module of Node.js

Sync:

```
var fs = require('fs'); /* Put it where other modules included */
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/src/assets/data.json', 'utf8')); /* Inside the get function */
```

Async:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data;
fs.readFile('/src/assets/data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  data = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Please read the official documentation before applying the code, and also feel free to check other examples on Node File System.

Source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011078/4590997)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local rest server and return json format saved in one file by :

File app.js

```js
'use strict'

var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  let urlInfo = url.parse(request.url, true); // host, pathname, search
  let method = request.method;

  if (method == 'GET') {
   console.log(urlInfo.pathname);
  if (urlInfo.pathname.includes('request1') ) {
  sendResponse('./request1.txt',response)

    } 
  } else {
    sendResponse("", "")
  }
}).listen(3000,"192.168.0.1");       // change your local host here
console.log("Start server at port 3000");

function sendResponse(filename,response) {
 var sampleTxt = path.join(__dirname, filename);
 console.log(filename);
 fs.readFile(sampleTxt, function(error, data) {
   if (error) return console.error(error);
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "If-Modified-Since"});
     response.write(data);
  response.end();
   
 });
}
```

In file request1.txt => save response format as you want

```js
[
  {
    "uuid": "id1",
    "userId": 80778,
    "mac": "mac1",
    "name": "Living & Dining Room"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "id2",
    "userId": 80778,
    "mac": "mac2",
    "name": "Bed Room"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "id3",
    "userId": 80778,
    "mac": "mac3",
    "name": "Kitchen"
  }
]
```

Run app.js