# NodeJs JSON parsing issue

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I have a .json file where i have people's names stored. I'm reading the content from this file using the file system from Node Manager and then I'm trying to convert this json to string and parsing it to JS object. After parsing it to JS object i get as type string instead of object. 
Here is the example json file :

```
{
"21154535154122752": {
    "username": "Stanislav",
    "discriminator": "0001",
    "id": "21154535154122752",
    "avatar": "043bc3d9f7c2655ea2e3bf029b19fa5f",
    "shared_servers": [
        "Reactiflux",
        "Discord Testers",
        "Official Fortnite",
        "Discord API"
    ]
    }
}
```

and here is the code for processing the data:

```
const string_data = JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync('data/users.json', 'utf8'));
const data = JSON.parse(string_data);
console.log(typeof(data)); // <-- this line here shows the type of data as string
const results_array   = Object.values(data);
```

where fs is the file system package from npm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON object into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory)

Comment: Also [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5726729)

Comment: I have tried all those methods but i still get the type string for unknown reason.

Comment: I would recommend to do a console.log() after each statement and see its format, and so its easier to understand where and whats going wrong. also assign fs.readFileSync to a variable and then reuse it. its more readable IMO.

Comment: if i use this line of code var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/users.json', 'utf8')); i get undefined : 1 {

Comment: I need to use JSON stringify at all costs because the JSON parse doesnt accept the json but when i use it i dont get the object from JSON parse

Comment: Just use `require('./data/users.json')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**don't use `JSON.stringify`** as it is further changing the string representation of JSON object. An example of what is happening is below

Imagine if you have a data in your file as shown below

```
{
   "key": "value"
}
```

When you read the file (using `readFileSync`) and apply `JSON.stringify`, it is converted to a new string as shown below. You can notice that the double quotes are now escaped

```
"{\"key\": \"value\"}"
```

Now when you will parse it using `JSON.parse` then instead of getting the desired `object`, you are going to get back the same string you read from the file.

**You are basically first performing and then undoing the stringify operation**

Comment: I get it now but when i use the other way around i get this error: **undefined: 1 '{' SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0**

Comment: can you print the string you received from `readFileSync ` using `console.info` and check if that's correct?

Comment: Yes everything looks fine. But cant get rid of this error.

Comment: When i print the string in the console i dont receive with the quotes at the ends is that something that i should worry about @S4beR ?

Comment: i assume you are seeing something like {"key": "value"}? This representation is fine

Comment: Aight then. Still i cant figure out how to fix this problem.

Comment: Facing similar situation, did anyone resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Okay so fs.readFileSync returns a string so you dont need to use stringify

```
var fs = require('fs');
var read = fs.readFileSync('data/users.json', 'utf8');
console.log(read);
console.log(typeof(read));
const data = JSON.parse(read);
console.log(typeof(data));
```

You will see it returns an object

Comment: I dont know but  i get the error **undefined: 1 '{' SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0**

Comment: just to make sure, you have a folder called data and inside has users.json right?

Comment: it stays with the same problem @AmirHosseinRd

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/users.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(typeof(data)); // <-- this line here shows the type of data as OBJECT
const results_array   = Object.values(data);
```

Comment: i really dont know what I'm doing wrong maybe it is from the json that is not constructed well.