# How to loop through JSON file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im working on a Discord bot with commands for premium members.

buyers.json:

```js
buyers.json:

{
  "buyers": [
    {
      "id": "331499609509724162"
    },
    {
      "id": "181336616164392960"
    },
    {
      "id": "266389854122672128"
    }
  ]
}
```

Snippet of the code:

```js
case "spotify":
            var uID = message.author.id;
            for (let i = 0; i < ftpr.buyers.length; i++) {
                if (uID === ftpr.buyers[i]) {
                    var _embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setTitle("Spotify")
                        .addField("Username", "testsda@yahoo.com")
                        .addField("Password", "ithastobe8")
                        .setColor(0x00FFFF)
                        .setFooter("Sincerely, LajgaardMoneyService")
                        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL);
                    message.author.send(_embed);
                    console.log(message.author + " Just used the command !spotify")
                }
                
            }
            
            break;
```

Everything works except the for loop and if statement. Its like it aint getting the id's.

```
var fptr = require("./buyers.json");
```

**EDIT:**
my json file looks like this:

```
{
  "buyers": [
    {
      "id": "331499609509724162"
    },
    {
      "id": "181336616164392960"
    },
    {
      "id": "266389854122672128"
    }
  ]
}
```

It has some id's from people.
In my app.js `var file = require("./file.json");` is used to import. Lets say that I change one of the ID's then I have to reload the app.js to update it. If I don't my checking mechanism isn't using the updated version of `file.json`
How should I go about updating the file every time that a function is being used?

Comment: Are you actually exporting the object, or just declaring it? Any console errors?

Comment: No errors at all. The ID's in the JSON file are the same as "message.author.id" but it isn't looping through the json file.

Comment: If the `for` loop isn't iterating at all, then `ftpr.buyers.length` is 0 or undefined - add log statements around those lines to check what it really is

Comment: Note that if you *actually* have a JSON, you have to parse it first.

Comment: shouldn't it be `uID === ftpr.buyers[i].id` instead of `uID === ftpr.buyers[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the *uID*, which I assume is a string, to each object in the array (which *contains* a string).

Try comparing to the id attribute of the buyers objects:

```
if (uID === ftpr.buyers[i].id) { }
```

Comment: `console.log("1");
                if (uID === JSON.stringify(ftpr.buyers[i].id)) {
                    console.log("2");`

Is not working. It isn't coming to "2"

Comment: You don't need `JSON.stringify` as that will return the id wrapped in quotes. Just compare `uID === ftpr.buyers[i].id`.

Comment: How can i add a new `"id":"new user"` so there'll be four users in the json? :D

Comment: Just add it to the array as you would in javascript - `ftpr.buyers.push({id: 'new user'})`

Comment: Thanks, but when I have to reload the app.js program in order to update the json file. How can I live update?
I have tried `ftpr = require("./buyers.json");` In hope that it would update. But that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think `require()` works like that. You can probably set up node to reload whenever a file is changed, or poll the file regularly for changes. You will probably get a better answer if you ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes before I can ask another one.

Comment: lol fair enough - if you're fine with the entire node process restarting when you change the json file, check out [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

Comment: I have the bot opened. Then I decide "nah, this dude is not cool, im gonna remove his id" If he then tries !spotify it still gives him the token even tho i have removed him. The bot has to run 24/7 so i can't restart the program every time someone buys premium

Comment: You need to periodically reload the json file or load it every time you need to compare, depending on use case. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011078/2336208).

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'buyers' of undefined`

Comment: I'd have to look at the code - post a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `message.author.id` and ftpr.buyers id's have the same type, the `ftpr.buyers` is an array of objects containing id of string. You should console.log the type of `message.author.id` by doing `console.log(typeof message.author.id,message.author.id)`

You could simplify the code by having an array of strings containing the id's before your switch case:

```
const ids = ftpr.buyers.map(b = b.id);//this is now ["331499609509724162",...]

  case "spotify":
      if (ids.includes(message.author.id)) {
        var _embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle("Spotify")
          .addField("Username", "testsda@yahoo.com")
          .addField("Password", "ithastobe8")
          .setColor(0x00FFFF)
          .setFooter("Sincerely, LajgaardMoneyService")
          .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL);
        message.author.send(_embed);
        console.log(message.author + " Just used the command !spotify")
      }

    break;
```