# Extract data from specific JSON field, use it as variable, and update the field value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, geolocation

I need to change the origin value to lat/lang coordinate (from another geoJson file) instead of country name:

```
index = [
  {
    "Name": "Aish Merahrah",
    "Origin": "Egypt",
    "Description": "Made with fenugreek seeds and maize; dough allowed to 
ferment overnight, then flattened and baked."
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ajdov Kruh",
    "Origin": "Slovenia",
    "Description": "Made with buckwheat flour and potato."
  }
]
```

so the result would be something like:

```
  {
    "Name": "Ajdov Kruh",
    "Origin": "46.151241, 14.995463",
    "Description": "Made with buckwheat flour and potato."
  }
```

I'm not sure about the workflow, do I need to extract the JSON value variable and somehow use that variable to obtain lat & lang data? Btw I *need* to use only JS/JQuery and Node.

Comment: From where is lat/lang coming?

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the lat/lOng, or how to modify the contents of `index`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Modify the content of index (by changing **origin value** to lat/lang) depends on its original country name.

Comment: How are you getting the values for lat/lang? How do you know that the value is for Slovenia and not some other place? Where is the connection?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal the json array is something like `"Slovenia": "46.151241, 14.995463", "Egypt": "26.820553, 30.802498"` so yeah the field name is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your geoJson has the following structure (country name as key and lat/long as value):

```
geolocation = {"Slovenia": "46.151241, 14.995463", "Egypt": "1, 1"}
```

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate on `index` and replacing `Origin` of each object with the values from `geolcoation`.

```js
index = [
  {
    "Name": "Aish Merahrah",
    "Origin": "Egypt",
    "Description": "Made with fenugreek seeds and maize; dough allowed to ferment overnight, then flattened and baked."
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ajdov Kruh",
    "Origin": "Slovenia",
    "Description": "Made with buckwheat flour and potato."
  }
]
geolocation = {"Slovenia": "46.151241, 14.995463", "Egypt": "1, 1"};
result = index.map(function(obj) { obj['Origin'] = geolocation[obj['Origin']]; return obj }); 
console.log(result);
```

You can even use `forEach` to iterate above and it will still change the `index`, since changes are done in reference objects.

Comment: Thx :) Is there any way I could use file path instead of the array? like `index = './index.json'` or sorta?

Comment: depends, `index.js` file has to export an array in that structure using `module.exports` ; only and only then you can do `index = require('./index.js')`

Comment: Sorry, I mean index.json, does it works in the same way?

Comment: I meant json***

Comment: try searching for it, answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011078/1376448 can help. it's out of scope of this question

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

```js
let index = [{"Name":"Aish Merahrah","Origin":"Egypt","Description":"Made with fenugreek seeds and maize; dough allowed to ferment overnight, then flattened and baked."},{"Name":"Ajdov Kruh","Origin":"Slovenia","Description":"Made with buckwheat flour and potato."}];
let lat = {"Slovenia": "46.151241, 14.995463", "Egypt": "26.820553, 30.802498"};
index.forEach(o => o.Origin = lat[o.Origin] ?  lat[o.Origin] :  o.Origin); 
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the object indices and then edit the values with your values.

Assume the given JSON data:

---

```js
// Creates an Object
let index = [
  {
    "Name": "Aish Merahrah",
    "Origin": "Egypt",
    "Description": "Made with fenugreek seeds and maize; dough allowed to ferment overnight, then flattened and baked."
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ajdov Kruh",
    "Origin": "Slovenia",
    "Description": "Made with buckwheat flour and potato."
  }
]

console.log(`Original Origin 1: ${index[0].Origin}\nOriginal Origin 2: ${index[1].Origin}`);

// Iterate over indices
for(let i=0;i<index.length;i++) {
  // Edit the value
  index[i].Origin = "1234/1234"
}

/*
// Using forEach
index.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.Origin = "Your Value";
});
*/

console.log(`Edited Origin 1: ${index[0].Origin}\nEdited Origin 2: ${index[1].Origin}`);
```