# JSON Variable for a nodejs script

Tags: node.js

im searching for an idea to fix my problem. First of all, there is a server.exe software, that can load some stuff. But if i change something, it needs a restart, but not, if i use a json file to store account names. Look:

```
    const allowedPlayers = 

    [

    "Socialclubuser1", 
    "Socialclubuser2", 
    "Socialclubuser3"

    ]

mp.events.add("playerJoin", (player) => {

if (!allowedPlayers.includes(player.socialClub)) {
    player.notify('Youre not whitelisted!');
}

});

mp.events.add("playerJoin", (player) => {

if (!allowedPlayers.includes(player.socialClub)) {

    player.kick('Youre not whitelisted!');    
}

});
```

i would use account.json, and insert there the stuff but how?

greetings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Create an account.json file and require it using require on start.

```
// account.json
// ["Socialclubuser1", "Socialclubuser2", "Socialclubuser3"]

const allowedPlayers = require("./account.json");

// rest of the code
mp.events.add("playerJoin", player => {
  if (allowedPlayers.indexOf(player.socialClub) === -1) {
    player.notify("Youre not whitelisted!");
    player.kick("Youre not whitelisted!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i got this:

TypeError: allowedPlayers.includes is not a function
  if (!allowedPlayers.includes(player.socialClub)) {

Comment: hahha it was ur code. includes is es6+ feature try with .indexOf i have updated solution

Comment: if i use my old code it works :D im completly confused

Comment: index.js:5: TypeError: allowedPlayers.indexOf is not a function
  if (allowedPlayers.indexOf(player.socialClub) === -1) {

Comment: //accounts.json
["Socialclubuser1", "Socialclubuser2", "Socialclubuser3"]

Comment: can u post ur account.json. i think ur account json is wrong

Comment: to check u can use, const allowedPlayers = require("./account.json"); console.log(typeof allowedPlayers)// this should return object, console.log(Array.isArray( allowedPlayers))//true

Comment: Hmm, now it works, but i need already to restart the server himself. I hoped it works without this step :(

Comment: yes, require is sync and u have to start again. Else use https://github.com/typicode/lowdb for auto-sync in memory db.

Comment: Hm, i will see, seems complicated.