# Is it possible to read/write to a file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, discord.js

**This is *not* for a browser.**

I intend to make a "blacklist" array for my bot, which will prevent users from running commands. However, I can only seem to do this on the actual bot file as I haven't found a way to do an external method.

What I'd want to do is have my main bot file as normal, but have a blacklist.txt with an array including their username, discord account ID and extra notes which can be accessed at any time by admins using a command.

This is what I'm using:

```js
var blacklist=[
    {username:'',userid:'',notes:''},
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with node.js(a platform based on javascript)
Here is an example how to do that [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)