# Get Username and Password from locally created .json file in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have created a basic login page with username, password input fields and a button. Also created a .json file which contains username and password. Now when I open login page, instead of typing username and password manually in the fields, those input fields should read from locally created **.json** file. How can I solve this?

Please help me get this answer. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you are trying to implement the "Remember me?" functionality, I encourage you to use a library like "react-native-keychain", which allows you to store credentials in a secure way.

Comment: But if you insist on a json file, you will most likely need to use react-native-fs
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir Thanks for response. No, am using a plain login page with username, password and login button. That username and password fields should read inputs from local .json file.

Comment: Can you tell me when this json file will be created?

Comment: Let me explain the scenario. I created a react native project. In this, I just created a login page with username, password fields and a button. And I created a .json file which consists username and password. Now in login page, instead of typing username and password, I need those fields get read from .json file.

Comment: I see, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory
The answer from Travis Tidwell is pretty staright forward

Comment: @VenkatSai You could import your json file like this `"import json from '../../file.json";`
and use that username and password while initializing the state.
Something like this :-
`const [email, setEmail] = React.useState(json.user.email);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// login.json
{
    "username": "testing",
    "password": "testing"
}


// UserTextInput.js
import * as loginData from './login.json';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const UserTextInput = () => {
  const [username, onUserNameChangeText] = React.useState(loginData.username);
const [password, onPasswordChangeText] = React.useState(loginData.password);


  return (
<>
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onUserNameChangeText(text)}
      value={username}
    />
<TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onPasswordChangeText(text)}
      value={password}
    />
</>
  );
}
```