# How do I open and read from file line by line (JavaScript) and save in list?

Tags: javascript, text-files, readfile

I have a text file which contains a list of words. I would like to open it, read it line by line and save its content as a string list, so that each word becomes an elemetn of thes string list. The I need to shuffle it to randomise the order. Could someone please explain me how to do this with JavaScript? I am very lost and would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)

Comment: What kind of environment are we talking about? A webbrowser? A server (like NodeJS)? And where is this file stored?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to read data from textarea and then shuffle it
https://github.com/reboot13-git/shuffle/blob/main/app.js