# Read value of docker config from nodejs app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-swarm

I have created a docker config from a json file, I need my node.js app to read the value(json) from the configs, how can I achieve that?

```
docker config create my_config ./config.json

>dg426haahpi5ezmkkj5kyl3sn

docker config ls

>ID                          NAME                CREATED             UPDATED
 dg426haahpi5ezmkkj5kyl3sn   my_config           7 seconds ago       7 seconds ago
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)

Comment: not really, I need to access the data stored in [docker configs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access docker configs they are mounted into services. This can be done on the `docker service create` command line but usually via the [configs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#configs) compose directive.

`compose.yml`

```yaml
configs:
  node_config:
    external: true
    name: my_config

services:
  my_node_service:
    image: node:lts
    configs:
      - source: node_config
        target: /app/config.json
```